# How to randomly split a data frame into halves that are balanced on subject and item

Tags: r

The following randomly splits a data frame into halves.

```
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HirokiYamamoto2531/data/master/data.csv")

head(df, 3)
#   dv   iv subject item
#1 562 -0.5       1    7
#2 790  0.5       1   21
#3  NA -0.5       1   19

r <- seq_len(nrow(df))

first <- sample(r, 240)
second <- r[!r %in% first]

df_1 <- df[first, ]
df_2 <- df[second, ]
```

However, in this way, each data frame (df_1 and df_2) is not balanced on subject and item: e.g.,

```
table(df_1$subject)

# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
# 7  8  3  5  5  3  8  1  5  7  7  6  7  7  9  8  8  9  6  7  8  5  4  4  5  2  7  6  9 

# 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
# 7  5  7  7  7  3  5  7  5  3  8 

table(df_1$item)

# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
# 12 11 12 12 9 11 11  8 11 12 10  8 14  7 14 10  8  7  9  9  7 11  9  8 

# There are 40 subjects and 24 items, and each subject is assigned to 12 items and each item to 20 subjects.
```

I would like to know how to split the data frame into halves that are balanced on subject and item (i.e., exactly 6 data points from each subject and 10 data points from each item).

Comment: Maybe package [BalancedSampling](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=BalancedSampling).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi, thank you for your comment, I will take a look at the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `createDataPartition` function from the caret package to create a balanced partition of one variable.

The code below creates a balanced partition of the dataset according to the variable `subject`:

```
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HirokiYamamoto2531/data/master/data.csv")

partition <- caret::createDataPartition(df$subject, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
first.half <- df[partition, ]
second.half <- df[-partition, ]

table(first.half$subject)
table(second.half$subject)
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible to balance two variables at once. You can try balancing for one variable and checking if you're happy with the partition of the second variable.

Comment: Hi Denis, thank you for your response. If you find a way to split a data frame into halves balanced on both subject and item, please share it here! Thank you.